# SPARQL Query to delete all blank nodes with in a Resource

Tags: sparql, rdf, turtle-rdf, blank-nodes

I am writing a SPARQL query that should delete all triples within in this resource.

```
prefix oslc: <http://open-services.net/ns/core#>
prefix example: <http://rdf.company.com/ns/something/net#>
prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
prefix dcterms: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>
prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>

example:Resource2
        a                oslc:ResourceShape ;
        oslc:describes   example:Resource2 ;
        oslc:property    [ a                      oslc:Property ;
                           oslc:isMemberProperty  true ;
                           oslc:name              "pgn" ;
                           oslc:occurs            oslc:Zero-or-one ;
                           oslc:valueType         xsd:integer ] ;
        dcterms:title    "Resource2"^^rdf:XMLLiteral .
```

I have tried:

```
 DELETE
    { ?s  ?p   ?o } 
  WHERE 
    { 
      ?s  ?p   ?o .
      FILTER  ( ?s IN ( <http://rdf.company.com/ns/something/net#Resource2>))
    }
```

However, id does not delete the blank node within it:

```
[ a                      oslc:Property ;
  oslc:isMemberProperty  true ;
  oslc:name              "pgn" ;
  oslc:occurs            oslc:Zero-or-one ;
  oslc:valueType         xsd:integer ]
```

It is pretty obvious because the filter specifies a specific subject and the blank node does not have that subject.

Any idea how can I delete the blank node as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you do not have nested blank nodes. Try this:

```sql
PREFIX example: <http://rdf.company.com/ns/something/net#>

DELETE {
    ?s  ?p   ?o .
    ?o  ?p1  ?o1 .
}
WHERE {
    VALUES (?s) { (example:Resource2) }
    ?s  ?p  ?o .
    OPTIONAL {
        ?o  ?p1  ?o1  .
        FILTER (isBlank(?o)) 
    }
}
```

Related question: [Delete blank node from ontology through SPARQL UPDATE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44330216/delete-blank-node-from-ontology-through-sparql-update).